# Switch a 12V 3.3A component from an Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, switch

I need turn off and turn on component from an Arduino UNO.

[image: Block diagram showing the power source, the component and the Arduino]

How can I do that? I am thinking about some transistor (IRF 530N) but I am not sure about it.

Please give me a beginner advice how to implement such a switch.

EDIT: Is this realy good for my problem? 
[image]

Comment: Maybe a relay would be easier?

Comment: Are there any advantages using relay instead of transistor?

Comment: @RogerRowland is this relay good for me? https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Fz85OVXXXXaXXVXXq6xXFXXXz/C18-2016-1pc-1-Channel-12V-Latching-Relay-Module-with-Touch-Bistable-Switch-MCU-Control.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relay, as pictured, is a good choice. It provides complete galvanic isolation and switches the power properly.

Another option is to use a MOSFET that can handle enough current (an N-channel switching the ground as a *low side* switch, or a P-channel switching the power which is itself switched by an N-channel, as a *high side* switch).

Comment: Upvoted, but the OP should be aware that a [flyback diode](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/110576/36731) across the relay coil may be needed, especially if they use a relay that isn't in a ready-made module.

Comment: You only need that if you are wiring it yourself, in which case you would be following a tutorial. With a module like the one pictured it is all splayed and there is no need for more components.

Comment: A simpler relay board than that shown might be better.  The one shown in question is constantly powered by 12 VDC on the DC+, DC- lines.  It is toggled by pressing the button or by a contact-closure on the pins of the white connector.  Amazon and ebay links: https://www.amazon.com/Wrisky-Channel-Latching-Bistable-Control/dp/B01IOTKAFS http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-Channel-12V-Latching-Relay-Module-with-Touch-Bistable-Switch-MCU-Control-/301820150781

Comment: Yeah, on closer inspection that one looks odd. You want one of the simpler ones. Sainsmart make some good ones.

Answer (score 2):

I've just bought a few STP16NF06L fets for this very purpose, N channel MOSFET.

The key part of that part number is the L at the end. This indicates low (or Logic) gate threshold, which means it will switch on fully at 5v gate drive, unlike most fets which are sort of conducting at 5v but need 10v to reach their specification (like an IRF530N).

The 16 and the 06 are 16 amps and 60 volts respectively.

You can get about 25 of them for the same price as a UNO, depending on supplier, in the UK [here for instance](http://cpc.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/stp16nf06l/mosfet-n-ch-60v-16a-to220/dp/SC11129)

Comment: I think you mean STP16NF06L About one third the price of a UNO clone.

Comment: @Jasen No, see the link in the answer

Comment: you wrote '60' in your text but the part number is '06'.

Comment: @Jasen, why so I did! Thanks. I get cross-eyed with long part numbers, especially when the voltage part drops the trailing 0.